# How do I soft lock a state in Corda?

Tags: corda

In Corda, how can I softlock a state to prevent it being selected from the vault by another flow? How do I release the soft lock? Will it be released automatically at any point?

Answer (score 3):

You soft-lock a state in a flow using:

```
serviceHub.vaultService.softLockReserve(
    runId.uuid, 
    NonEmptySet.of(stateRef)
)
```

Where:

- `stateRef` is the state you want to soft-lock
- `runId` is a property defined in each flow

By locking the state in this way, the soft-lock will automatically be released when the flow that soft-locked it ends (either successfully or in error).

You can also release the soft-lock using:

```
serviceHub.vaultService.softLockRelease(
    runId.uuid, 
    NonEmptySet.of(stateRef)
)
```

You are not obliged to soft-lock the state using the flow's `UUID`. You can provide a custom `UUID`, providing additional control over when the soft-lock is released.